# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid url: Finished: FAILURE

Tags: tomcat, jenkins

I am trying to deploy a very simple application on Jenkins server. I completed all the steps to link the application to jenkins. And when I tried to deploy the application on the tomcat server,using Jenkins deploy plugin, it just failed with the following exception

Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Gitcolony notification failed - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid url: 
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Can you add more information? With only this we can't help you too much...

Comment: @DanielMajano : PLease refer updated description of query, and let me know in case more details required.

Comment: can you provide the screenshot of tomcat configuration and also Execute Windows batch command screen shot